# Is web push notifications worth it?

Tags: notification

I have seen an increasing amount of websites using web push notifications. If you are not familiar with it, you accept notifications like this:

[image]

And then receive a notification like this:

[image]

My questions is, from your experience, how well does these convert? Is it worth investing into implementing it? From my research, it appears that it is relatively complex to piece together.

Comment: Yahoo mail is a web application and specifically a messaging application. Notifications are very useful there.

Comment: What kind of website do you have? Your talk of "convert" sounds like you have something entirely different in mind.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Those screenshots are not mine, just random ones from Google to demonstrate web push technology to the few who are yet to discover them. With convert, I mean, how well do people click on the notifications that they receive generally? Do web push provide a reasonably good click rate?